# unknownhostexception of a socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

sort of a simple issue but I'm terrible in networking so here goes:

im trying to connect to an ip and port with this simple line :

```
socket=new Socket(String ip,int port);
```

however i'm getting unknown host execption , even though that ip do exists (I can ping it successfully)

I do have the uses INTERNET permission.

Comment: do you use the IP-adress or the DNS name?

Comment: I use the Ip address

Comment: Do you execute this on a real device or in the simulator? Please check that you don´t have made a typo?

Comment: I used 2 different real devices and it's the same .

Comment: Do you ping from these devices? If you ping from your computer, it is not the same as from the devices. The devices could have a different way of reaching the device you are trying to connect. So I think that this is not a programming error, but a network issue. (From what you are describing.)

Comment: I ping it from the device using a 3rd party app "PIND & DNS" . and it pings ok

Comment: pinging is not enough, is port open?

Comment: Add more details, like the code for the server you're trying to connect to

Comment: @Sharpedge this is all I have , just an ip and a port to open a socket to . do I need anything else?

Comment: Just make a simple test scenario, since android socket programming is the same in java se, make a simple java client in your System(PC) and then run client see if it works or not and try to ping the ip from `cmd` see if that works.. The server you're trying to connect must be on the Internet and not running on the localhost